# Want to put a 4.6 directory in Core Project

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core, nopcommerce

I have one of my first .net core projects and need to include a subdirectory off my website with NopCommerce with is .net 4.6.

How can I put this in say a shopping directory off the main directory?

I'm using the non-source version of nop commerce so I can't just import a new project into my existing project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Until [`NetStandard2.0`](https://github.com/dotnet/standard/blob/master/docs/netstandard-20/README.md) comes out (Later this year) and you use it's compatibility shims you can't.

If you can't wait for `NetStandard2.0` you will need to make this NopCommerce section of your site a entirely different project, you then need to deploy it as a child application under your site.